# Scipy fsolve cannot take sparse matrix as jacobian

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the following code, which works fine (except of course it does not converge):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

T = 100

def recurrence(p):
    return p[2] - p[1] + 100 

def equations(p):
    n = len(p)
    return [p[0], p[n-1]-1] + [recurrence(p[i-1:i+2])
                               for i in range(1, n-1)]

def jacobian(p):
    J = np.ones((T+1, T+1))
    return J

p = np.ones(T + 1)
sol = fsolve(equations, p, fprime=jacobian)
```

However, when I changed the jacobian to return a sparse matrix, it does not work anymore:

```
def jacobian(p):
    J = np.ones((T+1, T+1))
    return csr_matrix(J)

TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'fprime' argument 'jacobian'.Shape should be (101, 101) but it is (1,).
```

Is there a workaround here? Of course this is just an example, but I am working with another system with a much larger value of T.

Comment: Looks like this is a long-known issue, both with root search and minimization: [Better routines for large-scale root finding](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2309). The underlying Fortran code requires dense Jacobian, and nobody has written its equivalent to support sparsity.